# How does Kafka store messages offsets on a local computer?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-python

How does Kafka store messages on a local server or laptop?

I'm new to Kafka and just playing around with the tech for now but I'm curious to the answer because I started by looking at the Kafka Quickstart page to just start a Kafka service on my laptop.  I sent several test messages and from some code, saw my topic had 100 messages.

Somewhere along the way, I read I can change where to store the logs in `config/server.properties` under a setting `log.dirs`.  The default is set to `/tmp/kafka-logs` so again, just to experiment, I shut off my Kafka service, recursive copied (cp -r) the dir to `/home/username/kafka-logs` and restarted the service.

To my surprise, the offset was reset to 0.  Shut off the Kafka server, went back to reset the `log.dirs` setting to be `/tmp/kafka-logs`, etc. etc. and when I checked, the offset was 100.

I had performed a recursive copy of the contents of the /tmp/kafka-logs dir so why did my laptop think the offset was 0?  Why did I "lose" my messages?  How does Zookeeper play into this and how do I check the contents of Zookeeper if it does?

I got some code from https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html

This is how I knew the offset had changed when I recursively copied my initial directory.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError    

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])

future = producer.send('my-topic', b'raw_bytes')


# Successful result returns assigned partition and offset
print ('topic is after this')
print (record_metadata.topic)
print ('partition is after this')
print (record_metadata.partition)
print ('offset is after this')
print (record_metadata.offset)
```

Comment: How did you check the offset ?

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper does not store offsets, but it has its own dataDir setting you could look at.

In the log directory, you'll find some index and timestamp files along with individual segments that encode an offset number within the filenames themselves. This allows for admins or the server to know which segment range contains specific offsets. It's not clear how you "restarted the service", but data in /tmp is always removed when restarting your machine, so best not to keep anything permanent there

The answer is the same, no matter where you run Kafka... There's a feature called tiered storage, where data can be offloaded to remote storage such as S3, however